# Change field value and trigger onchange event on button press

Tags: odoo

Very simple example: I added `Change to default partner` button (`type="object"`) on the invoice object. When I press it, a function is called which returns an ID (or other values too) of the default partner. How can I change the `Partner` field that it would trigger `onchange` event of that field (it would react as if I changed it from the UI)?

Answer (score 0):

If its a button, then in the button object write the partner ID to the invoice object that we get from the function you have said, and if you want to do the onchange function of partner, then call the onchange function inside the button function which will return a dictionary and take the 'values' from that dictionary.
For example:

```
def button_change_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    ##Your function to get partner id
    partner_details = self.onchange_partner_id(cr, uid, [], partner_id,context)#please replace with your actual onchange functionality and its arguments
    partner = partner_details['values']
    partner.update('partner_id': partner_id)
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, partner, context)
    return True
```

Comment: Please note that doing this way will "save" the modification. Once the user clicked on your button, it's done, even if he doesn't save.